# Partial results if a Vespa-query times out

Tags: vespa

If one document in the result-set is a huge document (several MBs), then:

- The query times out (it seems that querying is fast - but creating snippets using `summary: dynamic` times out)
- `children: [...]` contains only garbage information

Is one of these solutions possible?

- If Vespa can't answer `field: [...]`, it should at least answer the document-id, e.g. `id: "id:post:post::12345"` instead the `id: "index/content/0/..."`
- Only the snippets of the huge document should time out (currently all `children: [...]` return `"id": "index/content/..."`)

Example:

```
{
  "root": {
    "id": "toplevel",
    "relevance": 1,
    "fields": {
      "totalCount": 60
    },
    "coverage": {
      "coverage": 100,
      "documents": 1427628,
      "full": true,
      "nodes": 2,
      "results": 2,
      "resultsFull": 2
    },
    "errors": [
      {
        "code": 12,
        "summary": "Timed out",
        "message": "timeout waiting for summaries from sc0.num0"
      }
    ],
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/939fc4e6c4c9576cd77a12f3",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/45ee850d113ea6e6c42f2f9f",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/b9fcf825622f9ec8c0ea4e4d",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/1e1c4a96617fa6571c3c5ce7",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/2550e74ff60e88710f1f4f26",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/d1dd0fb89cea4613132a76f6",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/92a8c4abe0e358e3dab36fbb",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/bc36fea47a7628648d89e1b0",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/804475ba69aaa691de930e10",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/0577e69b0824684948027fc3",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/1b1f1144aa80385aca9a6027",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/34f8ddeca987fe2d77069009",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/f1befbe5d773e19811790e11",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/af2e009dd5ab895b1e3f9ff1",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/862f42f5c322642198b1f267",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/6d1fb4c45beb641fe1ce17ec",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/f9797f6e747b33b992faffb3",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/6a3e15cfab492c4a428ad529",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/9eb6407921012c10deb70115",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/905360bc8da5ff1b0b452246",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/24277dd2eef4167cec1bcf8a",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/a207cf989e02b1443d662cf1",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/bae6cb8b6e9fbc1032cb1ee4",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/24b0cd6cd7251074a9dea836",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/95b0f46b8fa9d22d497b08fc",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/41d534f99d1a27f6a0d2032b",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/c13287b86341bfbddda08b3a",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/59874c4cbff45ac155da5b11",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/28a1e4e530064836716e8175",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/8ebdc951376c0a82cafee577",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/79bcd638b357820e6f8ac10d",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/866db8cd10611dbc898fe5ec",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/a1444ef7d27205b34c60ff25",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/c82d1c8b0a134413203dde58",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/29c349724f46f9c1a7448eab",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/96f0f6cb2789f521c71318ca",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/b5b8046218c23d4c08fea8a7",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/2d4f7cf4e3c8d57e8dc7b401",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/562104630c6a15a001b0718c",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/dac419d3bcc45e7422548e74",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/9a4bb96ea031b3891a7f8d12",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/9b67994ac2d440bd6ac69d19",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/a7dbbc02b8889271441dfdc4",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/acdc61985bbdc43ca5cfaf56",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/a1429d9aa68422e0384f682e",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/11b0377300156b23c5a893fa",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/6d8075a57eef79a9f7060989",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/565b12cee0eccded7f384fb1",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/93c46b96dccd2ed8e52c6ae4",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/26acfa4c314761921da624a4",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/c99f784fa9d31a93c7b72ef0",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/88099aad4415647d62d705d9",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/b80c189a7e125a17a04c703e",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/3dea2a9e7e13211c0706e846",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/f1bdfae364ff4ad2bfee6236",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/7cc8a3c625ce3a11383c6157",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/44ddd465721f9dbf66f15f64",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/53d09e41a0a488c9ceffd4d7",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/76b024d20a1a78e255420e80",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      },
      {
        "id": "index:content/0/a4ddfd13bd4cace8984f90dc",
        "relevance": 0,
        "source": "content"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General:

1. It's not expected that it should take that much longer to generate snippets for large documents - how large are the problematic documents? How much time has passed before timeout? (You can find timing details by adding e.g &tracelevel=5 to the query.
2. It's most definitely not expected that snippets contains garbage information, could you show an example of what you see? Are you sure this isn't a client-side problem?

To your concrete questions:

- The id is part of the summary so it cannot give you the full id out of the box if the summary request fails. You can do this yourself if you like by putting the id in a different summary class and requesting that first (from a searcher doing two "fill" calls for the different summary classes).
- There is one summary request (typically for multiple id's) to each partition node. It would be possible to return what we have when you get close to the timeout but as far as I remember we don't do that for summary requests today.

Anyway, before considering workarounds let's find out the reason for this, I can't recall this having been a problem with any application before. I suggest you create an issue at https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues as it is more suitable for doing this.

Comment: You are right. Using `weakAnd()` makes the query blazing fast.